# Alguém sabe como resolver o problema de System.FormatException("entrada de caracteres incorretos)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Alguém sabe o que poderia estar causando o erro de Exceção nesse código?(sim, sou iniciante)

```
using System;
class Aula06 
{

    static void Main() 
    {



        double valorCompra = 5.50;
        double valorVenda;
        double lucro = 0.1;
        string produto = "Pastel Chinês";

        valorVenda = valorCompra + (valorCompra * lucro);


            Console.WriteLine("Produto......:{0,15}", produto);
            Console.WriteLine("Val.Compra....:[0,15:c}", valorCompra);
            Console.WriteLine("Lucro........:{0,15:p}", lucro);
            Console.WriteLine("Val.Venda........:{0,15:c}", valorVenda);
            Console.WriteLine("Final do Programa.");
            Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Boa tarde,

Acredito que você tenha utilizando um [ por engano logo após os :, substitua por { na linha abaixo:

```
Console.WriteLine("Val.Compra....:[0,15:c}", valorCompra);
```